# Compute the class number of $R=\mathcal{O}\cap\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{51}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> What is the class number of $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{51})$.

Could you please explain.

Comment: what you mean by $\mathcal O$ ?

Comment: ring of algebraic integers

Comment: @user104078 What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So you want the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 51)$. the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 51)$ is 2

Comment: i am not sure of my solution. i just  want to compare with another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general approach that will allow you to compute the class group. See chapter 8 of an [Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory](http://modular.math.washington.edu/129-05/notes/129.pdf) by William Stein for more details.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{51}]$. Since $51\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, we know that $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathcal{O}\cap \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{51}]=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{51}]$. The discriminant equals $4\cdot 51=204$, and  by applying the Minkowski bound it follows that $$|Cl_K|\leq \sqrt{204}\cdot \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^0 \frac{2!}{2^2},$$ and so $|Cl_K|\leq 7$. In particular, the Minkowski bound implies that we may find integral ideals with norm $\leq 7$ as representatives for each element in the Class group. Each such representative is a product of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$, and by the multiplicativity of the norm, $N(\mathfrak{p}_i)\leq 7$ for each $i$. If $\mathbb{Z}\cap \mathfrak{p}_i=p\mathbb{Z}$, then $p|N(\mathfrak{p}_i)$, and so $p\leq 7$. Thus it follows that the class group is the group generated by the prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ lying over the rational primes $2,3,5,$ and $7$. From here, the problem is reduced to computing the ideals that lie over the primes $2,3,5,7$, and if you are not entirely sure how to proceed there, see chapter $5$ of the book by Stein.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\cap \mathfrak{p}_i=p\mathbb{Z}$ not $\mathbb{Z}\cap \mathfrak{p}_i=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Amine: Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: prime 7 is not included.